# place-image not defined in Dr-Racket

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages

I wrote a simple code in Dr-Racket and it is not working. Here is the code:

```
(place-image (circle 5 "solid" "green")
             50 80
             (empty-scene 100 100))
```

I have selected the BSL language for compiling but it is giving me the following error:

> place-image: this function is not defined

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

If you're following with recent versions of Dr. Racket and "How to Design Programs, Second Edition", you should add the following to the top of your code:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
```

The end result would be the following:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image)

(place-image (circle 5 "solid" "green") 50 80 (empty-scene 100 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the image teachpack.